# Free monoids on posets

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, posets

I've suddenly found myself working with some free monoids $F(S)$ in which the set $S$ is a poset, and the order extends to an order $F(S)$, satisfying
if (but not only if) $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_r, t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_r\in S$
and $s_i  \leq t_i$ for all $i$, then  $s_1s_2\cdots s_r \leq t_1t_2\ldots t_r$ in $F(S)$.

Roughly speaking, in my context, the partial order reflects the dependency relationships between the cones in a CW complex.  It is entirely possible for the same partial order on the generators to be extended in different ways, depending on the homotopy properties of the space.

It seems like there could easily be a well-developed theory of such objects, and I'd appreciate any pointers to the literature.  (A google search turned up nothing.)

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplication respects the partial order"? the order is a priori on $S$, not on $F(S)$.

Comment: Do you mean a quotient of the free monoid?

Comment: Are you looking for a left adjoint to the forgetful functor from pomonoids to posets?

Comment: @YCor Clarified!

Comment: @SamHopkins No, it is genuinely free.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg It's like I've found a new gadget, and I'm looking for the instruction book.  I don't specifically have in mind that left adjoint, but I'd be happy to read about it.

Comment: It seems that the poset you defined is just the disjoint union of $S^n$ over all $n\geq 0$; how much more could there be to say about it?

Comment: Do you mean $s_i\leq t_i$?

Comment: This seems to just be the disjoint union of the product orders on the sets $S^n$ and then observing that concatenation obviously respects this.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I don't think so.  For example, say $S = \{ x,y,z\}$ with $x< z$ and $y< z$.  Then in the extended partial order, it can happen that $xy< z$ or not.

Comment: I thought you were defining the order that way.  Then your question is ambiguous since there are many orderings extending the ordering on S.

Comment: @SamHopkins I said if and did not mean only if -- clarified now.

Comment: I see, thanks. So as Benjamin Steinberg notes you are not really talking about a single construction.

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, that's right.

Comment: This looks a bit like term orderings except that they often require total orders.

Comment: The compatible partial orders on the free monoid form a compact totally disconnected space and the space of such orders that agree with the original order on S is a closed subspace. If S is finite it is even clopen. Do you want a description of that space?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Sure! If you make it an answer, I'll certainly upvote it.

Comment: I don't know a description of that space.  It might be massive

Comment: Does the order on F(S) have to restrict to the original order on S or can it extend the order?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I definitely want the order on $S$ to remain unchanged.

Comment: OK. So if S is not totally ordered we can't first make the order total.